# Fileoutputstream in eclipse. relative path

Tags: java, eclipse, fileoutputstream

is there a way to save a .txt file in eclipse?

Currently I'm doing:

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\mytxtfile.txt", false);
```

I want it to be in the eclipse folder from the project and not an absolute path.

Comment: `.\\mytxtfile.txt`? But maybe you should consider using  "resources"

Comment: Just saving using a relative path should place it somewhere in the Eclipse folder.  Have you tried doing that?

Comment: `FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("mytxtfile.txt", false);` should create the file at the root of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("mytxtfile.txt", false);
```

If you want to use a folder within the project root I recommend this:

```
File root = new File("yourfolder");
root.mkdir(); //this makes sure the folder exists
File file = new File(root,"mytextfile.txt");
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
```

To get the install location of eclipse for eclipse 3.3 (i don't know why you would do this, but still) `System.getProperty("eclipse.home.location");`

For newer eclipse versions i don't really know.

Comment: It's not in my project but where my eclipse is installed.

Comment: @Joe i can't help you with that, but i suggest you edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can set any initial folder you want in the Eclipse app launch configuration. It is the project root by default but this is not ideal; best is to use some folder like 'run' inside the project that you can add to .gitignore.

Then just empty path (`new File("")`) resolves to that folder, and you can also specify sub-path if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, newFileOutputStream("C:/Users/xxxx/mytxtfile.txt",false));
```